# AzerothCore.Can I use my DDNS hostname in realmlist table?

Tags: ip, hostname, azerothcore

I am configuring my first AzerothCore server. I got to the part where I configure the acore_with database's realm list table's address field. Can I use my ddns hostname here or do I need to use the dynamic public IP and change it every time my IP resets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your ddns hostname, you just need to make sure the right ports are  opened and your machine is reachable using that address from outside (you can try `ping` to make sure of it).